# How can i monitoring apache2 status using icinga2

Tags: icinga2

I want to know how can monitor apache status of clients using icinga2.
I successfully monitoring sql and other basic monitoring.but i have no idea how to monitor apache status

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nagios plugins in Icinga2. [This plugin looks like it could work.](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache/check_apachestatus/details)

Answer (score 0):

Most times it should be enough to monitor your HTTP and/or HTTPS Port.
Additionally you can monitor strings which should be on the page or the duration of your certificate.